# pip error looking for private package in pypi

Tags: python, pip

I have a package in a private repo (blob storage) that has an `install_requires` from pypi repo. I am running pip as follows

`pip install --upgrade mypackage -i https://example.com/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/`

but it fails with the following error

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/mypackage/`

the verbose output is (I've deleted some lines)

```
Looking in indexes: https://example.com/, https://pypi.org/simple/
2 location(s) to search for versions of mypackage:
* https://example.com/mypackage/
* https://pypi.org/simple/mypackage/

Starting new HTTPS connection (1): example.com:443
https://example.com:443 "GET /mypackage/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Analyzing links from page https://example.com/mypackage/
  Found link https://example.com/mypackage/mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (from https://example.com/mypackage/), version: 0.0.1
  Found link https://example.com/mypackage/mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz (from https://example.com/mypackage/), version: 0.0.1
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/mypackage/
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/mypackage/" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/mypackage/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13
Status code 404 not in [200, 203, 300, 301]
```

So it finds my package, and then ignores it.

(I'm kinda new to python / pip so I may be doing something stupid)

I am running this on ubuntu 19.04 
using these versions

```
(env) ubuntu@ubuntu19:~/staged/packages$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /home/ubuntu/staged/packages/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(env) ubuntu@ubuntu19:~/staged/packages$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Comment: If you say your package is in a private repo, might I understand it is not in pypi? If this is so, it is (as expected) not finding your package in pipy. Did you try `--index-url=https://example.com/mypackage` (instead of `--extra-index-url`)?

Comment: Also, versions you are using might help ;). [This](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6799) might bring some light into your issue.

Comment: thank you @MikeMajara that fixed it - if you want to write an answer I'll mark as correct - ( fixed with `pip install -U pip`)

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between [`--extra-index-url` and `--index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-i). The first one searches through several urls and, depending on versions, it appears to have some problems recovering from errors as can be found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6799)

Solution would be indicating that your repo is the only one where to search for your package with `--index-url=https://example.com/mypackage/` or in your case try to check that your are executing latest pip version trying to upgrade with `pip install -U pip`.

Comment: Upgrading `pip` fixed this problem for me. (`pip-18.1` → `pip-20.1.1`)

Comment: extra-index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple